# MySQL for 1-to-1 relation with relational integrity

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

[image]

I'm trying to write a create table statement for the relationship above.  I'm not sure if I've represented it correctly but basically every outlet has one manager and every manager manages one outlet.  I believe that either one of the primary keys from either table would be able to supply the primary key to the relationship table, can I just pick either of them?

I've also been told that I don't even need to create a separate table for the relationship unless it was a many-to-many relationship?

I'd also like to have some sort of constraint (if thats the right word) where if a store cant be deleted if a manager is attached and also can't delete a manager if they are attached to an outlet.

I've written a create table statement which I think is right but i've been doing this stuff for about 2 weeks and I really have no idea if it is going to behave the way I want:

```
CREATE TABLE Managers
(
    mgr_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    mgr_name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (mgr_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Outlet
(
    store_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    store_name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (store_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Store_Manager
(
    mgr_id int(10) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    store_id int(10) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (store_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (mgr_id) REFERENCES Managers(mgr_id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Will those statements create tables that behave according to the requirements?

Thanks

Comment: Why have separate tables?

Comment: its only a small part of a much larger ER diagram.  the managers table will form a relationship with employees and each employee will have a "line manager".  I'm aware managers are a type of employee so they could be included in the employee table however the requirements I have is that they should be treated as separate groups...

Comment: @ikeelu (Sorry for the offtopic): Also I've played with MySQL a lot in such complex DB-things, and in my experience it is totally incapable for any more complex things as a primitive, low-end record store. In your case I would try to use foreign keys in both tables, extended with constraints, and I would switch to an usable SQL ASAP (f.e. postgresql).

Comment: MySQL may be inappropriate for some high-end tasks. For this kind of thing, it's just fine. Hell, if it's good enough for Facebook...

Comment: Still, the store manager table is not required

Comment: Someone, somewhere, will eventually be very annoyed with the naming discrepancy between `managers` (plural) and `outlet` (singular). Probably also with ID field names like `manager.mgr_id`, when instead of the redundant `manager.mgr_id` they could be using the consistent/easier to remember/deduce `manager.id` (and `outlet.id`, etc.)

Comment: I equally dislike @Thernys naming policy, but I agree that there should at least be a policy - and abbreviations like `mgr` (and the use of 'store' in place of 'outlet') just drive me nuts.

Comment: @Strawberry So if I completely remove the store_manager table, how do I represent the relationship between the tables outlet and managers (continuing without having the managers stored in the outlet table)

Comment: By removing the bit in parentheses. I'm not saying it's wrong; it's just unnecessary